# How can I place the Variables in the side "y" of the barplot?

Tags: plot, statistics

The text of the variables cannot be read, I have already tried with the "cex.names" but they are too long. How can I put the variables in the "y" side, and the number of times in the "x" side?

```
barplot(table(somalia$strike_type), cex.names = 0.5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhoG3.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Is this related to 'R'?

Comment: Please upload the data and some code so we can reproduce what you did and help fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `horiz = TRUE` to your [barplot](https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html).
Like so:

```r
# Creating data to visualize:
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)

#
barplot(counts, 
barplot(counts, 
        main="Car Distribution",
        xlab="Number of Gears", 
        horiz = TRUE) # <---- This is what you want to add
```

## Output:

### With horiz = TRUE:

[image: Horizontal Barplot]

### With horiz = FALSE:

[image: Verrtical Barplot]